# What is the likelihood that in any group of people, at least two of them share a first name?

Tags: probability, statistics

In three distinct social groups in my life, there are individuals with the same first names that are friends and do similar things for fun. This got me thinking, what is the probability of such a thing? I gave it an attempt for a rough estimate with the 50 most popular names:

According to data [here](https://names.mongabay.com/male_names.htm), the top 50 names account for 47% of the men in the US. Rounding that to 50%, on average we get a 1% chance that any given man has a particular one of these names. Therefore, the odds that two people share one of these names is 
 $1 - (0.99)^p$,

where $p$ is the number of people

The result is, for 30 people, you get a 25% chance of a name collision, which seems plausible. How would I get a more accurate answer?

Comment: Beyond these very rough estimates things are quite hard. One of the main issues is that names are not statistically independent in friend groups: people tend to be friends with people similar to them in various ways, eg similar culture, and that’ll tend to cause their names to be more similar than chance. There was some process that caused the friend group to come together and it certainly wasn’t uniform random samples from the population of the US or the world! It seems hard to quantify this effect.